# How to do an if-else on a Flex component, based on the value of an object's member?

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, if-statement, boolean

When I click a row in the datagrid,  the "PeopleDetails" state is loaded. On the details state, I have a checkbox. This checkbox was automatically generated when I created the form. This is because the field in the People table is Boolean.

I actually do not want to have a checkbox, but I want the value Yes/No printed next to the label.

So I write some AS code embedded in the MXML code:

```
<s:Form includeIn="PeopleDetails">
 <s:FormItem label="Is Present?">
  <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
  if(person!= null ){
   if(person.present==true){
    Alert.show("Test - Yes");
   }
  }
  else{
   Alert.show("No");
  }
  ]]>
  </fx:Script>
  <s:CheckBox id="personCheckBox2" enabled="false" selected="{person.present}"/>
 </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

Just for testing purposes, I have Alert popups. Eventually, I would change to printing to screen the values Yes/No.

The problem:
-I do not know how to test whether the attribute *present* in the object *person* is true or false.
In the above, I get a FB complaint *1120: Access of Undefined property person.*

If I remove the AS code, the checkbox works fine. The checkbox uses person.present to know whether it should be checked or not. Why cannot I use person.present to do the if-else test?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading you right, you want a Yes/No value rather than a checkbox, this should do it for you:

Change :

```
<s:CheckBox id="personCheckBox2" enabled="false" selected="{person.present}"/>
```

To :

```
<s:Label text="{(person.present)?'Yes':'No'}"/>
```

So the new form looks like this :

```
    <s:Form includeIn="PeopleDetails">
        <s:FormItem label="Is Present?">
            <s:Label text="{(person.present)?'Yes':'No'}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't place ActionScript code on a script manner within `Script` tag. You can only place properties and methods there following OOP way. So put your code inside a method and call this method as a reaction on some event (`creationComplete` for example).

Answer (score 1):

I hope the above code is part of an ItemRenderer.

Just move the above Script block code to set data() function as below:

```
    override public function set data( value: Object ): void
    {
        super.data = value;

        if(person != null ){
            if(person.present==true){
                Alert.show("Test - Yes");
            }
        }
        else{
            Alert.show("No");
        }
    }
```

Also, I don't think Alert will work in Itemrenderer, so replace it with trace("") statement. Hope it helped.